# Machinery used to change train tracks

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to get an image of the machinery (that looks sort of geary and with long handles) that is used to change the tracks for a train.

I'm not looking for the name of the track parts. I'm looking for the name of the sort of gear like handle that you use to change train tracks.

What do you call this machinery?

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xfqt33x0QcQ

Comment: Right.   [A *switch.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1536&bih=747&ei=XmZSXLuGMMm0_AbKzYqwBg&q=railroad+switch&oq=railroad+switch&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1516.4086..4475...0.0..0.99.1200.15......3....1..gws-wiz-img.....0.7oSKiXF-nvg#imgrc=b6Yr7Eu16MvmNM:)

Comment: You mean the _machine_ (not engine) that changes the tracks?

Comment: see:https://www.narailproducts.com/glossary-of-terms/

Comment: @Cascabel, yeah, I only seen it in movies, a sort of gear like handle that y ou use to change train tracks

Comment: @Oldbag, no he's only showing the tracks, don't know if this is only in ancient trains that required manual intervention of track switching

Comment: As a general comment, questions about specialized terminology are usually best answered by subject matter experts. There is no obvious Stack Exchange site for this kind of question, but there are innumerable sites for railroad enthusiasts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://uk.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images?p=railway+points+levers&fr=mcafee&imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fl7.alamy.com%2Fzooms%2F7050ce958c864b47a399735484f3f596%2Fold-heavy-duty-points-lever-by-railway-track-dx5erw.jpg#id=0&iurl=http%3A%2F%2Fl7.alamy.com%2Fzooms%2F7050ce958c864b47a399735484f3f596%2Fold-heavy-duty-points-lever-by-railway-track-dx5erw.jpg&action=click) could be what you are after. In British English it's call a *points lever* and in US English it's called a *switch lever* because, as others have said, the movable tracks which actually redirect the trains are known by different names in Br and US English (in Br English one place where trains change track is called *a set of points*, usually shortened to points). However the lever is just the way in which points (I'm British and I'm just going to use one term) are controlled locally and manually.

Points were originally all controlled using points levers and some, particularly in marshalling yards, still are. However when signalling started to be controlled from manual [signal boxes](https://uk.images.search.yahoo.com/search/images;_ylt=AwrP4k3cyFJcOgUAygIM34lQ;_ylu=X3oDMTB0ZTgxN3Q0BGNvbG8DaXIyBHBvcwMxBHZ0aWQDBHNlYwNwaXZz?p=signal+box&fr2=piv-web&fr=mcafee#id=0&iurl=https%3A%2F%2Flondonbygaslight.files.wordpress.com%2F2013%2F07%2Fhebden_bridge_signal_box_5.jpg&action=click) some points were then controlled remotely from the box, although changing the points was still done manually with levers. Nowadays the points on main lines are usually operated electrically from larger signal boxes which can be many kilometres away from the actual points.

Comment: exactly, thank you very much, just needed this as a reference for 3D modelling. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's called a ***SWITCH***.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary 
(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/switch):

***switch***

noun

: a device made usually of two movable rails and necessary connections and designed to turn a locomotive or train from one track to another.

Comment: They are called points in British English.